# How to draw a top border on a bottom navbar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, navbar

I'm trying to draw a margin at the top of my bottom navbar on my Android app. Here it's what I have now:

[image: this is my app now]

What I'm trying to achieve is a black top border on the bottom bar. I created it using the split action bar. This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
        parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarSplitStyle">@style/MyBottomBar</item>

    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="@android:background">@color/white</item>
        <item name="@android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    </style>

    <!--bottom bar style-->
    <style name="MyBottomBar">
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar title text -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTextStyle"
        parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
            <item name="@android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I don't know what I need to give to the bottom bar and Android's documentation is not that clear. Help me please! Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new .xml file into the drawable folder. You can call it "bottom_navbar_background.xml". Draw a rectangle on the file like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:bottom="1dp">
        <shape
            android:dither="true"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />

            <solid android:color="@color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="1dp">
        <shape
            android:dither="true"
            android:shape="rectangle">


            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <padding
                android:bottom="0dp"
                android:left="0dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:top="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

put that as the background of the custom theme of the splitNavbar like this:

```
<item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/bottom_navbar_background</item>
```

et voila: you have the top border on your navbar!